# How to click on an element before the page is fully loaded i'm stuck, it takes too much time until loading completed

Tags: java, jquery, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I want to know if there is any way to force the browser stop loading, however the element i want to click on is visible, so that no need to wait untill fully loaded.

Comment: Did you intend to tag "java**script**"?

Comment: Maybe address why it takes so long for the page to load?  I feel like your burying the lead (or the issue in this case).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
WebElement myButton = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10))
  .until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("myButtonId")));
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("window.stop();");
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the onClick function between the head and body, at the top-ish. That way, the browser will see it first.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an explicit wait to detect the moment the element you want to click is clickable. Why waiting till the moment the page is fully loaded?

Comment: could you provide an example of how to do an explicit wait?