# Selenium ChromeDriver C# how to navigate page before it loads?

Tags: c#, google-chrome, selenium

I am testing data flow for a client's website. It has advertisements that take substantially longer to load than the data elements of each page that I would like to test with Selenium commands.

I don't have control over the ads and can't silence them.

I would like to navigate each page with clicks prior to the complete page loading. I know that this is possible because I can do it manually using the mouse. However, despite my attempts the stubborn chromeDriver will not begin automation until the entire page is loaded.

I am using C# .Net 4.6.1, chrome32_55.0.2883.75, and Selenium version 3.0.1.0.

Further, I am using the recommended Selenium page object model. I implemented WaitForLoad() like this:

```
    public override void WaitForLoad()
    {
        _isLoaded = Wait.Until(d =>
        {
            lock (d)
            {
                SwitchToSelf();

                return PageRegex.IsMatch(Session.Driver.PageSource);                    
            }
        });
    }
```

The PageRegex above will work but only after the full page is loaded. Which is frustrating because I can visually see that the text string that the PageRegex is designed to parse is on the screen. This leads me to believe that there is a setting elsewhere, perhaps while I am configuring ChromeDriver, that would enable me to parse the Session.Driver.PageSource prior to it being completely loaded.

This is how I am instancing the ChromeDriver:

```
            var options = new ChromeOptions();

            options.AddArguments("test-type");


            options.AddArgument("incognito"); // works
            options.AddArgument("--disable-bundled-ppapi-flash"); // works! this turns off shockwave
            options.AddArgument("--disable-extensions"); // works
            options.AddArguments("--start-fullscreen");

            string workFolder = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop) +
                                                 "\\SHARED";

            options.BinaryLocation = workFolder + @"\Chrome32\chrome32_55.0.2883.75\chrome.exe";
            var driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
            driver.Manage().Cookies.DeleteAllCookies();
            return driver;
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To interact with the page before it has finished loading, you can either lower the timeout and catch the exception:

```
IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));

driver.Manage().Timeouts().SetPageLoadTimeout(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500));

try {
    driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.deelay.me/5000/http://www.deelay.me/");
} catch (OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverTimeoutException) { }

// waits for an element 
var body = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(By.CssSelector("body")));
```

Or you can disable the waiting by setting the page load stategy to `none` :

```
var options = new ChromeOptions();
options.AddAdditionalCapability("pageLoadStrategy", "none", true);

IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));

driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.deelay.me/5000/http://www.deelay.me/");

// waits for an element 
var body = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(By.CssSelector("body")));
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried with ElementToBeClickable or VisibilityOfElementLocated methods of ExpectedConditions class. I think it should work in the scenario you mentioned.

```
WebDriverWait wdw = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(120));
            wdw.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.Id("ElementId")));
```

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to navigate each page with clicks prior to the complete
>   page loading

Do I understand you right that you want to click on some links while the page is still loading?
If you know which elements you are going to click, maybe you can do the same as in this question [How to click on an element before the page is fully loaded i'm stuck, it takes too much time until loading completed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41088182/how-to-click-on-an-element-before-the-page-is-fully-loaded-im-stuck-it-takes-t/41101146#41101146)